# Does Baahubali explicitly indicate that the cow scene is CGI?

Tags: indian-cinema, baahubali-the-beginning

I was watching *Baahubali: The Beginning* (acquired from questionable provenance) and during one scene, it had "C.G.I" in the corner of the frame as a watermark.

My first thought was that this was one of those where the person who "distributed" it decided to add his own credits into the movie. But I checked the rest of the film, and this only happens in one scene in the middle, the one where the prince dominates a feral bull by grabbing it by the horns and forcing it to the ground.

It occurred to me that there might be another explanation. While there are many CGI scenes in this movie (and indeed, in nearly all movies today), this is the one scene where it shows a character mistreating a cow/bull.

Is this included officially by the filmmakers to indicate that the scene was not real? Or do I just need to see if I can purchase a more legitimate copy of the film?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why this watermark is shown is to let audience know that animal included in this scene is not real and is made using CGI. Thus there is no animal harmed during making this film.

There are more scenes where this watermark is included in this film and its sequel. For example, it is shown when Bahubali enters the Mahismati kingdom after promising Avanthika to free Devsena.

I have watched this movie in a theater and on TV so I guess it's included in the distribution by filmmakers.

Comment: Thank you for confirming this. Do you know if it's specific to animal scenes, some other subset of scenes, or just CGI in general?

Comment: It's specific to animal scenes only even though there is a lot of CGI scenes in this movie.

Comment: Presumably, it's specific to the *cow* scenes, as Hinduism considers the cow sacred, and India has a history of debate on cow violence.  The CG logo may be saying "no cows are harmed--in fact, this isn't even a real cow!"

Comment: Even in the recent visit to The Kapil Sharma show, SS Rajamaouli Sir revealed that mostly animal scenes are created through CGI

Answer (score 2):

This '*making-of*' sequence, released by the film's VFX studio; [Tau Films](https://taufilms.com/) also contains the watermark you've mentioned, quite literally coming and going as the cow is shown in the scene.

It would appear that this is wholly intentional, presumably as a sop to audiences in India (the film's primary market) where depictions of a cow in distress would be controversial and frowned upon.